# Json object property undefined in IE8 only

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, internet-explorer

I'm trying to iterate through this array to pins on a map, in every browser it seems to work fine but in IE8 I get the error "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'top': object is null or undefined" If I change top to something else or remove it, IE just  says the same thing about left or name, etc. If anyone had any suggestions, they would be greatly appreciated.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var pins =  [
            { "name":"Mexico", "top":"154" , "left":"176", "imageFile":"Mexico.jpg", "soundMP3File":"Mexico_GMartinez_1.mp3", "soundOGGFile":"Mexico_GMartinez_1.ogg"},
            { "name":"Chile", "top":"261" , "left":"246", "imageFile":"Chile.jpg", "soundMP3File":"Chile_MVelasquez_1.mp3", "soundOGGFile":"Chile_MVelasquez_1.ogg"},
            { "name":"Trinidad and Tobago", "top":"182" , "left":"242", "imageFile":"TrinidadTobago.jpg", "soundMP3File":"Trinidad-Tobago_SHarris_1.mp3", "soundOGGFile":"Trinidad-Tobago_SHarris_1.ogg"},
            { "name":"Columbia", "top":"209" , "left":"227", "imageFile":"Columbia.jpg", "soundMP3File":"Colombia_JGordon_2.mp3", "soundOGGFile":"Colombia_JGordon_2.ogg"},
            { "name":"Canada", "top":"86" , "left":"208", "imageFile":"Canada.jpg", "soundMP3File":"Canada_KBretzer_1.mp3", "soundOGGFile":"Canada_KBretzer_1.ogg"},            
            ];

for(var i = 0; i < pins.length; i++)
    {
        jQuery('#map #pins-container').append('<a href="#" class="pin" style="top: ' + pins[i].top + 'px; left:' + pins[i].left + 'px;" pinindex="' + i + '" name="' + pins[i].name + '"></a>');
    }


});
```

Comment: You have a trailing comma after the last object in the array. Remove that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Guffa is right. The trailing comma on the 'Canada' line is invalid.

IE is the only browser that will actually complain abuot it, but it is techinically invalid everywhere.

In order to avoid issues like this, you should use tools like [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/), which will validate your Javascript code for coding common errors, including the trailing comma bug.

Comment: Note: JShint is integrated into JSfiddle.net. I recomment you to go that way.

Answer (score 0):

In **IE** If you give comma after last **JSON object** this is give error in **IE6,IE7,IE8.**

**So, Always remember this When ever you are writing Javascript,JSON**